# What's the difference between element~element and element+element

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between these two CSS selectors. I get the same result from them both.

HTML:

```
<div>One</div>
<p>Two</p>
```

[CSS Example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpufr/):

```
div+p {
background:red;
}
```

This gives the `<p>` element a red background.

[CSS Example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/S2sM5/):

```
div~p {
background:red;
}
```

This also gives the `<p>` element a red background.

So... what's the difference between these two selectors?

Comment: [The spec is your friend](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sibling-combinators).

Comment: Add another p to your html and you will find what the difference is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) :

> **E + F** an F element immediately preceded by an E element
>
> **E ~ F** an F element preceded by an E element

The important word is **"immediately"**.

In your HTML, as you have no other element, you can't see the difference but it's of course important in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Sibling:**

> div + p p elements that directly follow div elements

p + *   any elements that directly follow p elements

**Indirect Sibling**

> div ~ p   p elements anywhere after div elements

p ~ *   any elements anywhere after p elements

**Reference:**
http://www.princexml.com/doc/6.0/selectors/